Renaming OneDrive root folder
I'm writing in response of the question:
How can I rename my root OneDrive folder?
I found that this solution worked, but still there is a problem because there are now two folders for the same OneDrive account, and now the long name doesn't work. I need some help to remove the old name folder in Windows Explorer. I need to remove the "Facultad de Agronomía - Universidad de Buenos Aires" folder. Here is what I see.
Two folders error screenshot:
screenshot of error

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you try to stop OneDrive and then remove the old folder?

@RomeoNinov - In that case you go through OneDrive to change the location, modifying a single registry key, isn’t enough

@Ramhound, not sure about this way. I use: 1. logout from onedrive 2. stop it 3. remove the old folder 4. start it and following the process select different folder

Thanks, I've already done it but it still appears in Windows Explorer as the screenshot shows.
